# Apache Nifi processor that acts like a barrier to synchronize multiple flow files

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm evaluating Nifi for our ETL process.
I want to build the following flow:
Fetch a lot of data from SQL database -> Split into chunks 1000 records
each -> Count error records in each chunk -> Count total number of error
records -> If it exceeds  a threshold  Fail process -> else save each chunk to the database.

The problem I can't resolve is how to wait until all chunks are validated.
If for example I have 5 validation tasks working concurrently, I need some
kind of barrier to wait until all chunks are processed and only after that
run error count processor because I don't want to save invalid data and
delete it if the threshold is reached.

The other question I have is if there is any possibility to run this
validation processor on multiple nodes in parallel and still have the
possibility to wait until they all are completed.

Answer (score 2):

One solution to this is to use the `ExecuteScript` processor as a "relief valve" to hold a simple count in memory triggered off of the first receipt of a flowfile with a specific attribute value (store in the [local/cluster state](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#state_management) with basically a Map of key `attribute-value` to value `count`). Once that value reaches a threshold, you can generate a new flowfile to route to the success relationship containing the attribute value that has finished. In this case, send the other results (the flowfiles that need to be batched) to a `MergeContent` processor and set the minimum batching size to whatever you like. The follow-on processor to the valve should have its *Scheduling Strategy* set to `Event Driven` so it only runs when it receives a flowfile from the valve.

Answer (score 1):

Updating count in distributed MapCache is not the correct way as fetch and update are separate and cannot be made in atomic processor which just increments counts.

http://apache-nifi-users-list.2361937.n4.nabble.com/How-do-I-atomically-increment-a-variable-in-NiFi-td1084.html